# Unit Testing MVC Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, testing

I have an MVC Application along with a unit-testing project with a reference to my main project. Presently all my unit tests that involve database work are performed on the main application database.

Would it be best practice to create a replica db instead and store it in the testing project?

When i test creating new users i would not like them to be a part of the main database.
Is a replica database a good solution or would it be sufficient to delete anything I create in my teardown methods?

Any help would be great!

Comment: I'd create an in-memory database which is created and seeded for every test. That way you have known data and other tests don't affect each other.

Comment: Depends what you're unit testing - if it's your DAL, do as @dav_i says, otherwise, you should be mocking out dependencies so your database will never be hit anyway.

Comment: You aren't doing unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think running your unit tests on the main application database is not a good idea. Your unit tests will be more complex and you can get interdependence issues where forgetting to delete data from one test breaks another further down the track. These can be time consuming to track down and fix.

You can also end up with old test data polluting the database and increasing its size and requiring periodic cleanup. I have used both methods and find that creating a new database for every test or suite of tests is far more workable and easier to maintain.